# PASSWORD GENERATOR- if/else verifying strings

Tags: java, if-statement, passwords

I'm trying to verify a string. When the input box comes up, I type in the password "wolverhampton", yet I keep getting "Your password is incorrect" instead of "Your password is accepted".

What am I doing wrong?
I am a noob btw. Only been coding a few days.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class loops {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    String password;
    String number;
    password=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter password");
    number= password;
    if(number == "wolverhampton") 
    {System.out.println("Your password is accepted");}

    else {System.out.println("Your password is incorrect");
}
```

Comment: please add a tag stating the language you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made the classic mistake of using `==` instead of `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()`. You say that you've been only coding for a few days? Hopefully you're referring a good book & have gone through the theory part.

What you need to find out:

- Basic object-oriented concepts and the distinction
  between references & objects in Java
- How objects are stored in memory vs how String objects are stored in memory
- Effects of using `==` on primitives vs objects

  - and hence why we should use `.equals()` instead
- How the rules of `==` and `.equals()` change for String objects

These topics can be easily Google'd or searched in StackOverFlow itself. Oracle's Java tutorials are an excellent source too. Once you understand everything, then you'll also know why it's not a *good practice* to store passwords in Strings.